# Error updating Swift 1 accelerometer code to Swift 2

Tags: swift, accelerometer, swift2

I recently updated Xcode to version 7 which also includes Swift 2.
A lot of my code had errors and I managed to fix most of them except for one.

```
let manager = CMMotionManager()

if manager.accelerometerAvailable 
{
    manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.5
    manager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) 
    {   //  **Error on this line**
        [weak self] (data: CMAccelerometerData!, error: NSError!) in
        buffer = data.acceleration.y
    }
}
```

The resulting error is:

> Cannot convert value of type '(CMAccelerometerData!, NSError!) -> ()' to 
>   expected argument type 'CMAccelerometerHandler' (aka 
>   '(Optional, Optional) -> ()')

How do I go about fixing this error so my code works with swift 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
let manager = CMMotionManager()

if manager.accelerometerAvailable 
{
manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.5
manager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) 
{   
    data, error in
    buffer = data.acceleration.y
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to declare the type of the block

```
manager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {  
    [weak self] data, error in
    buffer = data.acceleration.y
}
```